# Sorting an array of arrays by specific index descending

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array below

```
Array
(
  [Prod1] => Array
    (
        [0] => $1,167,788.03
        [1] => 26,872
        [2] => 73.42
        [3] => 19.0%
        [4] => $1,134,106.83
        [5] => $1,681,843.02
        [6] => $3,098.65
        [7] => $42.20
        [8] => $-19.55
        [9] => $-9.60
        [10] => $43.46
        [11] => 0.97
    )

[Prod2] => Array
    (
        [0] => $6,730.84
        [1] => 161
        [2] => 0.44
        [3] => 13.7%
        [4] => $4,783.41
        [5] => $6,755.61
        [6] => $13.07
        [7] => $29.71
        [8] => $-27.30
        [9] => $-21.50
        [10] => $41.81
        [11] => 0.71
    )

[Prod3] => Array
    (
        [0] => $2,498,984.47
        [1] => 30,409
        [2] => 83.08
        [3] => 21.5%
        [4] => $3,026,866.16
        [5] => $3,850,645.25
        [6] => $8,270.13
        [7] => $99.54
        [8] => $-21.33
        [9] => $-8.19
        [10] => $82.18
        [11] => 1.21
    )
}
```

I am trying to sort it on descending order based of the index[0] and tried using different PHP built in functions but I was not successful on that.

Basically the desired result would be in the following order Prod3, Prod1, Prod2.

What would be the best way for solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposing $arr is the array you've displayed above, the below code should work in your case

```
$tmp_arr = array();
$sorted_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $val_array) {
    //removing $ and ,
    $first_index_without_dollar = str_replace(array("$", ","), array("", ""), $val_array[0]);
    //getting string as number in order to sort
    $first_index_without_dollar = number_format((float) $first_index_without_dollar, 2, '.', '');
    $tmp_arr[$first_index_without_dollar] = $key;
}
//sorting by key descending
krsort($tmp_arr);

foreach ($tmp_arr as $val) {
    $sorted_arr[$val] = $arr[$val];
}
```

Comment: THank you for this elegant code!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is the best way but the user function is fairly simple:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
 $x = (int)str_replace(['$',',','.'],'',$a[0];
 $y = (int)str_replace(['$',',','.'],'',$b[0];
 if ($x === $y) return 0;
 return ($x < $y) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Edit: I missed the format on the values the first time. And I would not have found it without Mohamad Attat's answer. The str_replace calls should fix it, iff you always have two decimals in your dollar amounts.